# Initiate Class On Demand

Tags: php, oop, initialization

I am trying to initiate a class on demand.

```
class MyClass{

    private $modules = array("mod1" => false);

    public function __get($name){
        if(array_key_exists($name, $this->modules) && !$this->modules[$name]){
            $class       = ucfirst($name);
            $this->$name = new $class();
            $this->modules[$name] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I then have another class, which then extends the above class. If I do the following the class doesn't get initiated, and I get an error `Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object`

```
class Home extends MyClass{

    public function main(){
        echo $this->mod1->get("cat");
    }

}
```

But if I do this, the class does get initiated.

```
class Home extends MyClass{

    public function main(){
        $this->mod1;
        echo $this->mod1->get("cat");
    }

}
```

Is there any way for me to initiate the class without having to add that extra line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return it after it's instantiated:

```
class MyClass{

    private $modules = array("mod1" => false);

    public function __get($name){
        if(array_key_exists($name, $this->modules) && !$this->modules[$name]){
            $class       = ucfirst($name);
            $this->$name = new $class();
            $this->modules[$name] = true;

            return $this->$name;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can do what you want:

```
class Home extends MyClass{

    public function main(){
        echo $this->mod1->get("cat");
    }

}
```

Comment: haha, wow, I can't believe I never thought of that, thanks for the help!